# Self-Contained Binary Package From Python Source

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to figure out a way to package my Python source into a binary form. I have several python scripts inside of a folder I named it src along side I have other folders that are non-coded source mostly input, output files and documentation and I would like to repackage that entire folder "src" into binary form. I see examples that developers when they package their programs they end up having lib and bin folders.

Any suggestion or guidance is very much appreciate it.

Thank you in advanced.